# Some hierarchy not shown in outliner

Tags: outliner

I have an object with several child objects, some of which are in different collections.  Some of the child objects in the different collections themselves have children.  In the outliner I can see the immediate child objects of the 1st object, with the ones in different collections greyed out.  What I don't understand is that, in the outliner, some of the child objects in different collections that have child objects of their own do not show the lower level child objects while others do.  In the included image, "edge ring 8.1", "track 8.1.1", "track 8.2.1" and "track 8.3.1" are all located in a different collection from the parent, and all have child objects of their own. In the collection where the child objects are you can see that the lower level child objects are there, but as you can see in the image only one of them shows the hierarchy in the collection of the top level parent.
[image: screen shot of hierarchy in parent collection]